# C#-Is there a way to get a do-while to accept OR statements?

Tags: c#, menu, user-input, do-while

I'm teaching myself some C# and got the idea to build a temperature calculator. I want to use a do-while loop to ensure the user picks a valid menu choice. What I tried to do was:

```
do
{
  //etc etc etc;
} (while menuChoice != 1||2||3);
```

In other words, keep doing what is inside the loop unless menuChoice is 1, 2 or 3. VS2010 Express tells me I can't do that. Is there a way to do this that way or do I have to do something else? Any suggestions on how to do this or should I use some other solution?

Answer (score 5):

```
do { // stuff
} while (menuChoice != 1 && menuChoice != 2 && menuChoice != 3);
```

Comment: It wouldn't let me us && either but I didn't try it with separate bool statements like that. I'll give it go!

Answer (score 3):

```
do {
    // etc.
} while(menuChoice != 1 &&
        menuChoice != 2 &&
        menuChoice != 3
  );
```

Each of the clauses of a conjunction must be an expression that evaluates to a `bool`. Note that `!= 2` is not an expression that evaluates to a `bool`. In fact, it's not even a legal expression. This is why you must specify `menuChoice != 2`.

Also, note that you should use `&&` because the clauses. You want `menuChoice` to equal 1, or to equal 2, or to equal 3. Therefore you want

```
!(menuChoice == 1 || menuChoice == 2 || menuChoice == 3)
```

as the condition in the `while` loop. By DeMorgan's Laws, this is equivalent to

```
menuChoice != 1 && menuChoice != 2 && menuChoice != 3
```

Comment: While it technically matches the op's pseudo-code, you might just as well write `while (true)`

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

How about this? this would allow you to have a non-contiguous set of numbers and is far more extensible than having a million || statements...:

```
int[] menuOptions = { 1, 2, 3 };
```

...

```
while(!menuOptions.Contains(menuChoice))
```

Comment: I think leppie has the answer

Comment: You don't need `new int[]` when declaring an `int[]` like that.

Comment: Tip: It would be better to use a `HashSet` if the options grow a lot, say 20 or more. A separate helper method with a `switch` would probably be optimal.

Answer (score 0):

Or:

```
do {
    // etc.
} while(menuChoice > 3 || menuChoice < 1);
```

Answer (score -1):

Just to provide *yet one more solution*:

```
using System.Collections.Generic; // for the List<T>
do
{
}
while (!(new List<Int32>(new[]{ 1, 2, 3 })).Contains(menuChoice));
```

And yes, this is not the *best* solution, it is, however, an alternative (and useful if your list of options grows).

Comment: You could import `System.Linq` instead, then the code would just be `new[] { 1, 2, 3 }.Contains(menuChoice)`

Comment: @Gabe: correct. -- And to whomever did, why the downvote though? What about that is a) not functional, b) off track, or c) not a solution to the original question? Can't win, even *with* disclaimers. :sigh:

Comment: Either way, this is major unnecessary overhead.

Comment: Maybe the downvote is because of the excess code. Rob's version has less overhead and IMHO is easier to understand.

Comment: @leppie: I never argued it was optimized or even ideal, I was just displaying another method. Not only that, given the level they appear to be in, some times it's a post like this that peaks curiosity about a library like `List` that let's them continue on their educational path. you never went searching for one answer and saw a library along the way and said "oh, neat"?

Comment: I for one appreciate the unorthodox approach :). Never know when it might be useful someday.

Comment: Not sure why you've been downvoted, once a the list of possible options grows to more than a few it's easier to add potential options to a collection and use contains rather than typing out `if x == option400` for each one. Would probably declare the collection outside the loop though.